# How do I increase the volume of file system root

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've installed it (Ubuntu 16.04.6) on a partition of my 128GB SSD so that I have a dual boot operating system (windows 10 and Ubuntu). However I keep getting a warning message saying 'The volume "Filesystem root" has only 82 MB disk space remaining' and I don't know how to expand it. I tried expanding the partition ubuntu is installed on while in windows but it wouldn't let me add any unassigned storage onto the partition containing Ubuntu.

I was wondering increasing the partition size is possible (or if that is even the problem) or if I'm better off creating a new partition in my 1tb HDD and installing it there instead since I can probably only add a few more gb to the SSD ubuntu partition at most.

```
john@johnubuntu:~$ df -h  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev  
tmpfs           1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run  
/dev/sda7       8.8G  8.3G   60M 100% /  
tmpfs           7.8G  205M  7.6G   3% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock  
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/sda1       496M   69M  428M  14% /boot/efi  
tmpfs           1.6G   72K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.